# os.EOL in Typescript+Node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, eol

How to use `os.EOL` in Typescript Node.js program?

```
import { EOL } from 'os';

console.log("text"+EOL);       // ???
```

This is not working.

I downloaded `os` with `npm i os -S` but in `node_modules/os/index.js` file is only one line: `module.exports = require('os')`. I don't get it..

Answer (score 4):

Its a commonjs module and not an es6 module. So you cannot use the

```
import {EOL} from 'os'
```

style because EOL isn't exported.

You import these modules using either

```
import * as os from 'os';
```

or

```
import os = require('os');
```

the former being more common as far as I've seen.

```
import * as os from 'os';
const { EOL } = os;
console.log("hello" + EOL + "world");
```

you may or may not need to `npm install @types/node` for typescript to know about `os`. with the types installed you can explicitly tell node to load the types up with

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It is worth noting that if your environment supports it, `import os from 'os';` is preferable to `import * as os from 'os';` as the latter is TypeScript specific, non-standard node-interop that will break in the future.

Comment: `import os from 'os';` is for importing es6 default exports... as of node 7.4 (or at least the latest node typings) that isn't valid.

Comment: It depends on the context. If you are using Webpack, SystemJS, or piping through Babel, use the default interop require syntax. `import * as x from ...` has nothing to do with NodeJS. It is a problematic TS construct for mapping ES Module Syntax onto CommonJS. That is why I recommend `import os = require('os')` in my answer.

Comment: `import os from 'os';`- TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript example.ts (1,8): Module '"os"' has no default export. (1192)

Comment: If you are targeting Node and using `--module commonjs` then use `require` if you are using another transpiler or a loader that provides interop, use `import os from 'os';` as that is what NodeJS will one day support. `import * as os` is bad legacy. That error is expected since you are running directly against node via `tsc --module commonjs` because typescrfipt does not have proper interop behavior. Please see https://github.com/nodejs/node-eps/blob/master/002-es6-modules.md

Comment: To understand why `import * as ... from` is broken, consider that ES Modules prohibit a namespace from being callable or constructable. Many modules imported this way actually export a callable or constructable.

Comment: `import * as os from 'os';` produces `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'os'.`
And I don't wanna require() next to my imports.. That's looks bad.

Comment: @tBlabs install `npm install @types/node` and maybe add `types: ["node"]` in your `compileOptions` in tsconfig.json... that will tell typescript compiler to use node typings, which includes the `os` module.

Answer (score 0):

You can use os library in the following way:

```
import * as os from "os";

os.EOL...
os.CpuInfo....
```

Comment: That gives me `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'os'. `. I use tsc 2.0.0, node 7.2.0, os 0.1.1

Comment: Did you install the NodeJs types?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but now-a-days you can do this:

1. Add `compilerOptions.module` & `compilerOptions.esModuleInterop` to `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```

2. Import like a module that has a default export:

```
import os from 'os';
console.log(os.EOL);
```